# Marketing Cloud : Is it possible to fetch categories (folders) for Classic content emails using REST API

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api

I am able to fetch the categories (Folders) associated with content builder emails using

endpoint : https://www.exacttargetapis.com/asset/v1/content/categories

Headers : 
content-type : application/json
authorization: Bearer XXXAuthorization TokenXXX

This only fetches the content builder folders. 
I am looking to fetch the classic content folders ( where the classic content emails are stored). Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use SOAP API to retrieve the Email folder hierarchy stored in Classic content.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/retrieving_the_email_folder_hierarchy.htm